# Read json subelement with ReadJSON in Jenkins

Tags: json, jenkins, jenkins-groovy

I have a packages.json file with this content:

```
{
    "packages": {
        "pkg1":{
            "Cpu": "2",
            "Memory": "8",
            "Disk": "100"
        },
        "pkg2":{
            "Cpu": "4",
            "Memory": "16",
            "Disk": "200"
        }
    }
}
```

I also have an environment variable `env.VM_PACKAGE` from another stage. I would like to get the Cpu, Memory, Disk values from specific package with this Jenkins flow:

```
stage('Parse package details') {
    steps {
        echo "Read packages JSON file"
        script {
            def props = readJSON file: "${WORKSPACE}/maintenance-vm/packages.json"
            env.PACKAGE_CPU = props['packages'].props["${env.VM_PACKAGE}"].get("Cpu")
            env.PACKAGE_MEMORY = props['packages'].props["${env.VM_PACKAGE}"].get("Memory")
            env.PACKAGE_DISK = props['packages'].props["${env.VM_PACKAGE}"].get("Disk")
        }
        echo "Cpu: ${env.PACKAGE_CPU} Memory: ${env.PACKAGE_MEMORY} Disk: ${env.PACKAGE_DISK}"
    }
}
```

so for example if `${env.VM_PACKAGE}` has value `pkg2` then the echo would write this: `"Cpu: 4 Memory: 16 Disk: 200"`

I tried to use single quotes, double quotes, no quotes around `${env.VM_PACKAGE}` but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is off. Try the following.

```
env.PACKAGE_CPU = props['packages'][env.VM_PACKAGE]['Cpu']
```